# How to execute a .RAR file

Tags: java, macos, command-line, jar, rar

I downloaded an application which was in `.RAR` file. I am having trouble executing the application. I have tried two ways of executing it.

First Attempt:

After viewing the `rar` contents, I figured out that it has proper manifest file (Stating the main class to execute), so i should change the file name to `.jar` and try executing it. I did that and ran the following command:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

And received the following error:

> Invalid or corrupt jarfile filename.jar

Second Attempt: I decided to extract the file and try it manually. I extracted the file on my desktop and it created the specified folder structure. And then I ran this command

```
java -cp .:./Users/My/Desktop/ExtractedFolder/ MainClassName.class
```

And received the following error:

> Could not find or load main class MainClassName

How do I execute this application?

P.S:
`ExtractedFolder` is the folder which was created after unzipping the file. It has heirarchy like

```
ExtractedFolder
|_ META-INF
|__|__MANIFEST.MF
|__org
|__|__folder_1
|__|__|__folder_2
|__|__|__|__folder_3
|__|__|__|__|__MainClassName.class
|__|__|__|__|__OtherClass.class
|__|__|__|__|__|__UtilFolder
|__util_1
|__|__SubUtil
```

Comment: you must provide the fully qualified class name.

Comment: And not the .class part. I would load that entire directory structure into a new JAR file and use java -jar.